# Can I sort a cakePHP select box based on a virtual field?

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Right now my select box is being created from a virtualfield in my `Players` class to be used in an `add.ctp` view for my `Statistics` model. The select box is currently being sorted by the id. I would rather it sort by the `Player.last_name`.

Here is my Model:

```
class Player extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Player';
    public $virtualFields = array(
    'name' => "TRIM(CONCAT(Player.last_name, ', ', Player.first_name))"
    );
    public $displayField = 'name';

    var $hasMany = array(
         'Statistic' => array(
             'className'     => 'Statistic',
             'foreignKey'    => 'player_id',
             'dependent'=> true
         )
     );  

}
```

this is what I'm using in my `add.ctp` view:

```
 echo $this->Form->input('player_id');
```

This is the current output (ordered by the player_id):

```
<select name="data[Statistic][player_id]" id="StatisticPlayerId">
    <option value="335">Smith, Jordan</option>
    <option value="336">Marall, Jabari</option>
    <option value="337">Rusell, Mike</option>
    <option value="338">Johnson, Calvin</option>
    <option value="339">Thompson, Daniel</option>
    <option value="340">Dennis, Jacob</option>
</select>
```

This is the desired output (ordered by the last name):

```
<select name="data[Statistic][player_id]" id="StatisticPlayerId">
    <option value="340">Dennis, Jacob</option>
    <option value="338">Johnson, Calvin</option>
    <option value="336">Marall, Jabari</option>
    <option value="337">Rusell, Mike</option>
    <option value="335">Smith, Jordan</option>
    <option value="339">Thompson, Daniel</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, you can order by virtual fields, but your virtual fields is `'name'` and not `'last_name'`. Try `$order = array('Player.name');`

Comment: I'll give that a shot, but in the meantime, do yo want to submit that as an answer so that if it's right, I can give you credit for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can order by virtual fields, but your virtual fields is `'name'` and not `'last_name'`. Try `$order = array('Player.name');`

Comment: I think that worked! However I had to add `var` in front of the `$order = array('Player.name');` because for some reason it was throwing a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION in /var/www/app/Model/Player.php on line 17`

Comment: Ordering by last_name should work as well. It would actually be better to order on `last_name, first_name` to sort the last name, then first name.